# Is this territorial or harsh play?

Tags: cats, behavior

So I have a female cat that has already had a litter of kittens and we decided to keep one of them. He is about 4 months old.

Well, mommy cat got pregnant again and just had 2 babies (I don't know how many she'll have through the night).

But I found the male kitten we kept either playing way too rough, or just straight up trying to kill one of the kittens because it has blood and wounds all over it.

I have no idea what to do about this situation and since I don't think they're safe I put him outside for the night. Has anyone ever heard or witnessed anything like this? I have no idea what to do and if I should stay worried

Comment: We have a couple of closely related questions. I am not sure they clearly address your question, but do talk about similar issues. [Will our cat try and hurt the new kittens he is related to?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7922/will-our-cat-try-and-hurt-the-new-kittens-he-is-related-to) & [Will neutering a male cat stop it from killing kittens?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5954/will-neutering-a-male-cat-stop-it-from-killing-kittens)

Answer (score 4):

Keep the mother cat and her babies separated from the other cat at all times, by sequestering one or the other in separate areas of the house. Keep one in a single room if you have to.

It does not matter what the male cat's intentions are, he is hurting the kittens, when he should be leaving them alone at this age regardless. When they are newborn, they cannot play at all.  It is clear he cannot be trusted with them. Therefore, for the kittens' safety do not let him near them, at least until you judge they are at an age where he can no longer severely injure them. Though seeing that he has already injured one, I'd probably wait at least a couple months, until they are quite big. Then you can try the normal, heavily supervised, cat introduction techniques.

I also recommend getting your female spayed. Having kittens every few months is very stressful on a cat's body, and you would avoid situations like this.

Comment: My living situation is very different from most people do it's gonna be very hard to keep them separated unless he gets put outside basically. And they are both getting fixed but the appointments are pushed back all the way to December so I've got some waiting to do

Comment: @CarlyKrolikowski there's nothing "special" about keeping animals sequestered. Do you have a bathroom with a door? There's an isolated space. A bedroom with a door? There's another one. Any room with a door that can be closed is an isolated space where you can keep the mother cat and kittens, and once they're weaned, get her spayed.